# Accessing extracted classes revision info in SVN

Tags: svn

So i have a SVN source-controlled class that expands over time and eventually needs to be split into two classes.  So i remove the relevant methods from the old class and move them to a new file.

However, the new class has no relation to the original class as far as SVN is concerned, and as such the change-log for the code in the new class is empty, even though there might have been several changes to the code when it existed in the old class.

Is there any way to make SVN associate a file with another so I can see the full revision log including prior to when the class was extracted?

If not, what work-arounds are used to inform other devs that the class's code used to be in another file?  Do i need to stick a comment referring to the previous file every time I extract a class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually if I split a file into two, I make a copy of it.

In the original I delete the first half, in the copy - another one.